# JQuery button Problems & onclick highlight input text?

Tags: jquery

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nuc/

My initial question was going to be regarding how to highlight the font size upon clicking the drop down as the following does not work:

```
$('#Font-Size input:text').text().highlight('12');
```

However what I have done seems to be buggy and not working at times.

I don't really know what to say is wrong as it doesn't always seem to be the same outcome, the only constant problem I don't know howt to fix is removing the on focus (default showing up) on the text input field.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: Can you please elaborate what highlight the font size means? Do you want to select the value 12 in textbox on click of the dropdown arrow?

Comment: @Raman - Yes, when you click on the drop down button I would like the text in the input field, of which currently says '12' to be highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the answers to the different questions:

1.) If you want to select the textbox value on click of Dropdown, you can use the `.focus()` method. On click event of the dropdown button, use something like:

```
$('#Font-Size input:text').focus();
```

to set the focus to the textbox which will automatically highlight the value in the textbox which is 12 currently.

Updated jsfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nuc/1/

Hope I have placed the `.focus()` at correct place. Please correct if by any chance it need to come in the proceeding if-else statement.

2.) To Unselect at any time you can use `.blur()` method.

3.) To remove the default style(outline) which comes on focus, you can use

```
* {
    outline : none;
}
```

at the top of the CSS file. This will remove the default outline from all the elements. Updated fiddle with this implementation is http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nuc/2/

Comment: Yes, this does the trick!  Is there an unselect function too for later usage? The only other thing is how do I remove the default on focus and whatnot for a text input field as my styles are being shown with others I have not implemented. Best Regards, Tim

Comment: @TimMarshall ... for unselecting you can use .blur()

Comment: Not sure about the default styles. Let me check and explore a bit more. And please mark it as answer and an upvote if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you and I always leave any pages I have not given the tick or thumbs up yet open. To be fair, you do deserve a thumbs up of which I'll do now but there are still questions to be answered and this will show up to others as being answered.

Comment: hmm.. U have a point :) I will also try to figure out the answers to you questions if i can :) Thanks

Comment: @TimMarshall ... please check the undated answer. Hope that solves all your problems. :) Let me know if I can help in anything else

Comment: I do have a couple of more questions regarding this section I am working on, however unless you would be willing to turn this into a chat, I'll add another question because you have answered all questions for this one and I am grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#Font-Size input:text').select()
```